# sessions getting expired after 5-10 minutes

Tags: php, session

I have implemented SessionHandlerInterface class and have written my own session functions.I used them to store sessions  in database.However,my sessions are getting destroyed even though the expiry time for them is atleast 3 hours,if session's value get modified the time changes from current time to next three hours.

```
public function write($id, $data)
    {
    $this->remote_write = new RemoteAddress();
    $this->ip_address_write = $this->remote_write->getIpAddress();
    $DateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $NewDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($DateTime . ' + 3 hour'));
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("REPLACE INTO Session SET Session_Id = ?, Session_Expires = '" . $NewDateTime . "', Session_Data = '" . $data . "', ip_address = '" . $this->ip_address_write . "'");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);

    // $result = mysqli_query($this->link,"REPLACE INTO Session SET Session_Id = '".$id."', Session_Expires = '".$NewDateTime."', Session_Data = '".$data."'");

    if ($stmt->execute())
        {
        return true;
        }
      else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }

public function destroy($id)
    {
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("DELETE FROM Session WHERE Session_Id =?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    if ($stmt->execute())
        {
        return true;
        }
      else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }

public function gc($maxlifetime)
    {
    $result = $this->link->query("DELETE FROM Session WHERE ((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Session_Expires) + " . $maxlifetime . ") < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()))");
    if ($result)
        {
        return true;
        }
      else
        {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

These are some of the functions that i have implemented,if anyone needs the whole code,i can upload that as well.

[image: session]

This is the phpinfo for my website.

What could be the reason for this weird behavior ?
Why does my session keeps destroying after sometime?

Update:

Database looks like this

[image]

Comment: session cookie lifetime? what are you actually setting it to when you send it out? I would `var_dump($_COOKIE);` to ensure it has the expected details when it comes back. I would also add logging to the write and destroy functions to see what they are actually doing and when. It should be possible to then work out why it isn't working as expected.

Comment: session cookie lifetime isn't dependent on the browser ? logging as in how ? tell me , i will provide you with as well. @RyanVincent

Comment: _logging_ - I have a 'logger' (monolog) started very early in the `application bootstrap` startup. So, I can write messages to a file from anywhere in PHP without it messing up screen display or causing the 'headers already sent' error. So, I can use it as  very simple debugging (print statements). It is often enough to get clues  about what is happening and is quick to do. `var_dump` an `print_r` output can be captured and sent to the log file. imo, It really is quite useful to have.

Comment: i do have an error logger, i could write my contents to it for the time being to figure out as what actually is happening @RyanVincent

Comment: i am not saving session cookie inside the db , just the info about the session cookie. @RyanVincent . I am getting my values but session is getting destroyed for no reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122623/discussion-between-botjr-and-ryan-vincent).